# Javascript If condition is not working if the array is larger

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Am a beginner to competitive programming i have been trying to solve a problem in hackerearth [Problem here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/the-amazing-race-1/). Mine problem solves only first test case When i found out the error the if part is not working properly for a particular test the test case is give below as well as the program

```
  1
  22
  289 558 271 15 492 853 988 834 766 573 316 959 192 7 730 277 631 97 717 
  185 514 86
```

My problem

```
function main(input) {
//Enter your code here
var data=input.split("\n"),templen=1,temparr=2,X,arr,len,temp,sight,min=0,ans;
var T=parseInt(data[0]);
for(var i=0;i<T;i++) {
    min=0;
    len=parseInt(data[templen]);
    arr=data[temparr].split(" ");
    arr.map(function(x) {
        return parseInt(x);
    });
    if(len===1) {
        ans=1;
    }
    //Looping from the first array element
    for(var j=0;j<len;j++) {
       temp=j-1;
       X=0;
       console.log("Value is " + j + " Array value is "+ arr[j]);
       //A while loop to find out if the current element is greater than 
       previous element it goes till the beginning of the array
       while(temp>=0) {
       //If the element is greater will increment X value
           if(arr[j]>arr[temp]) {
                X=X+1;
                console.log("Greater Temp arr "+ arr[temp]);
                temp--;
           }
        //If the element is smaller it will break out the while loop
           else {
                X=X+1;
                break;
           }
       }
       temp=j+1;
       //A while loop to find out if the current element is greater than 
       previous element it goes till the end of the array
       while(temp<len) {
       //If the element is greater will increment X value 
         of the array
           if(arr[j]>arr[temp]) {
                X=X+1;
                console.log("Temp arr "+ arr[temp]);
                temp++;
           }
           //If the element is lesser it will break out the while loop
           else {
                X=X+1;
                break;
           }
       }
       sight=X*(j+1);
       console.log("Sight is "+ sight + " X is " + X + " J is "+ j + " array value is " + arr[j]);
       if(sight>min) {
           min=sight;
           ans=j+1;
       }
    }
    console.log(ans);
    templen+=2;
    temparr+=2;
}
}

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
stdin_input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
main(stdin_input);
});
```

If you look at the arr[17] which is 97 how does the if condition works because its not greater than next element arr[18] which is 717 nor the previous element arr[16] which is 631 how it passes both If condition. Any help would be appreciated Thanks

The problem is https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/the-amazing-race-1/

Comment: You showed all your code, without commentary. Try to isolate and specify your problem. Here we barely can understand what happen

Comment: Am looping each element from my array from index 0 then am performing a operation for example(array[0] which is 289) checking that element if it is greater than next element(second while loop till the end of the array) i will increase the X value and previous element(first while loop till the beginning of the array)i will increase the X value. If the current element is lesser than the previous element the loop will break its same for next element too now my problem is for arr[17] which is 97 its lesser than both previous and next element but still it increments the X value.How is that possible

Comment: Added comments to my code bro

Comment: you could move the exit condition inside of the while condition.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry i didn't understand can you please elaborate?

Comment: please see my answer, there are single `while` loops without more `if` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an approach with two `while` loops, one for counting previous elements and the other for counting the following elements.

This proposal is not optimal, because I wanted to show the intermediate result set of counts.

```js
var data = [289, 558, 271, 15, 492, 853, 988, 834, 766, 573, 316, 959, 192, 7, 730, 277, 631, 97, 717, 185, 514, 86],
    count = data.map(function (a, i, aa) {
        var c = 0,
            p = i;
                                                // check previous elements 
        while (p-- && aa[p] < a) {              // decrement and check index and if
           c++;                                 // value is smaller than actual item
        }                                       // then increment counter

        p = i;
        while (++p < aa.length && aa[p] < a) {  // check following elements
            c++;
        }
        return c;
    }),
    result = count.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        return r && aa[r] * (r + 1) < a * (i + 1) ? r : i;
    }, -1);

console.log('index:', result, 'value:', data[result]);
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks may i know what this code does result = count.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        return r && aa[r] * (r + 1) < a * (i + 1) ? r : i;
    }, -1);

Comment: that checks the count and the multiplication with the position and returns the index of the greatest value. basically the sight, *X * P*.

Comment: There is another thing actually if i code without using if else there will be a problem lets take an example arr[0] which is 289 is not greater than next element arr[1](558) but if i use if else the X will be incremented one time in else(which i need according to the problem in simple terms i can say i want to increment X only if its failed for the first time). My X will be 1 but according to your code X will be 0. How do i solve that?

Comment: as i understand the requirements correctly, the count should count only the once who are before or behind without counting the actual element, according to the rules: "*number of drivers he can see in front of him + number of drivers he can see behind him*".

Comment: Exactly "number of drivers he can see in front of him + number of drivers he can see behind him" but if you look at the line below in that problem.    " As all the drivers are moving in a straight line, a driver i
i cannot see beyond another driver j if height of  j>= height of driver i." So if we take our same example arr[0] 289 is not greater than arr[1](558) but arr[0] can see him so he can see one car(arr[1]) so X should be incremented once. He can't see anything beyond that.